# Which timezone used in GCP Billing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is Billing Timezone "America/Los_Angeles" fixed for GCP? or it varies?

https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports#time_aggregation

A 24-hour time period in the Cloud Billing report starts at midnight US and Canadian Pacific Time (UTC-8), and observes daylight saving time shifts in the United States.

Comment: Account management questions, including billing and invoicing, are off topic here. You should talk to Google

Comment: No proper answer from google, so that asking here. If anyone knows the answer i can get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Google uses Pacific Time to calculate the billing period for all
  customers, regardless of their time zone.

  This is based on the
  [timestamp type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp_type).

> A timestamp value represents an absolute point in time, independent of
> any time zone or convention such as daylight saving time (DST), with
> microsecond precision.

- For conversion we use Timezone and aAs per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#time_zones)

> The following timestamps are identical because the time zone offset
> for America/Los_Angeles is -08 for the specified date and time.
>
> `SELECT UNIX_MILLIS(TIMESTAMP '2008-12-25 15:30:00 America/Los_Angeles') AS millis;`
>
> `SELECT UNIX_MILLIS(TIMESTAMP '2008-12-25 15:30:00-08:00') AS millis;`
>
> **Note** that not all time zone names are interchangeable even if they do
> happen to  report the same time during a given part of the year. For
> example, America/Los_Angeles reports the same time as UTC-7:00 during
> daylight saving time (DST), but reports the same time as UTC-8:00
> outside of DST. If a time zone is not specified, the default time zone
> value is used

- Billing Timezone "America/Los_Angeles" fixed for GCP and it takes
  from the [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (time zone database).
- For more information, you can contact [cloud billing support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing#contact-billing-support).